# Inbuild Asp.net validation controls are executed on server side or client side?

Tags: asp.net

Inbuild Asp.net validation controls are executed on server side or client side??

- The RequiredFieldValidation Control
- The CompareValidator Control
- The RangeValidator Control
- The RegularExpressionValidator Control
- The CustomValidator Control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default both. They execute client side when you click LinkButton/Button with CausesValidation="true" (they are putting required javascript into page). They execute server side when the PostBack is originated by LinkButton/Button with CausesValidation="true". There is also manual API for using them, both for client side (specific javascript methods) and server side (you can use Page.Validate() to enforce validation). Here you have some more reading: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479045.aspx